Dual boot SSD not detected Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Currently, I use Ubuntu in USB stick and I  can see my sdd that installed Windows. Recently I bought new sdd (Samsung 980 PRO NVMe M.2 1 TB SSD). I can see that sdd on Windows but I can't on Ubuntu. I only see Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible on dmesg
I tried RAID to AHCI, turned off safeboot.
Here is my lsblk output:
~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0   313M  1 loop /snap/code/166
loop3         7:3    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2318
loop4         7:4    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2264
loop5         7:5    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1439
loop6         7:6    0 149.6M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/507
loop7         7:7    0 262.1M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3728
loop8         7:8    0 269.8M  1 loop /snap/firefox/4698
loop9         7:9    0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/121
loop10        7:10   0  10.7M  1 loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop11        7:11   0 504.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/172
loop12        7:12   0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop13        7:13   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop14        7:14   0  10.5M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1046
loop15        7:15   0  10.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/1110
loop16        7:16   0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop17        7:17   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop18        7:18   0   476K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop19        7:19   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop20        7:20   0 149.6M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/497
loop21        7:21   0  74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1586
loop22        7:22   0   313M  1 loop /snap/code/167
sda           8:0    1  59.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2        8:2    1  58.6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0 930.6G  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0   849M  0 part

df -h
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        58G   34G   21G  62% /
tmpfs           7.7G   53M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        192K  103K   85K  55% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sda1       1.1G  6.2M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  140K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000


dmesg output

Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware. Even new may still have an update available. Compare to latest available on vendors' support site. sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl statusWindows may turn fast startup back on, double check setting. And make sure bitlocker is off.
